# Mobile first server - only last notification show up in Android Device when multiple push notification are sent

Tags: mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

We have implemented push notification for Apple and Android using mobile first server Push API. When we send multiple push notification to single user Apple devices will receive all the notices, but in Android only the last message shows up. Does any one know how to fix this issue. Is it related to Mobile first platform config?  Or is it a device issue?

Comment: just use different notification id or auto generated id

Comment: so how are you confirming only the last notification is received

Answer (score 0):

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ChimmerIntentService.this).setContentTitle(app_name).setSmallIcon(icon_ID).setContentText(message)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND).setAutoCancel(true).setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        notificationManager.notify(notificationTag, notificationID, notification);


In this method we pass notification id every time you need to pass unique id for each notification.

notificationManager.notify(notificationTag, notificationID, notification);

May be you pass the same notification id  every time when a new notification is comming because of same id it replace the privious one.
```

Comment: Is this solution for hybrid APP. I guess this is for Android only?

Comment: its for both you need to pass uique id everytime until all notifications are not clear from notification area